# New Cisco AIR-1602I-E-K9 AP not working on some ports

Tags: cisco, wifi, access-point

I have had this problem since last friday but cannot solve it. I gave it a lot of thought so posting here is my last option/hope.

We recently aquired 5 new Cisco AIR-1602I-E-K9, I configured them all (almost identically) and they all connect to the same Cisco 4500.

However, for some reason they only work on some ports. I mean, for example, if I connect one of them to the port Gi1/40 @ Cisco 4500 it works, they also work at port Gi6/30, but they do not work at some other ports that has the same minimal configuration, for example Gi1/41, Gi1/43...etc.

The new AP's do turn ON when I connect them, but they do not spread the wifi and if I check the port at 4500 it is "down down".

Any tips/help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance and excuse my english.

Comment: I don't know the 4500 range sorry but some Cisco kit comes with some but not all ports activated, you buy licences for the extra ports - probably not the situation but thought it worth mentioning.

Comment: First of all thanks for the quick reply. Regarding the ports, they are now used by AIR-AP1231G-E-K9 AP's so they are "activated" for sure. I have to replace them with our new 1602.

Comment: Do the different modules have different PoE capabilities?  Or are you powering the AP's locally?